# Using a csv feeder to check a count i.e. convert to Int

Tags: scala, gatling

I am using Gatling 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT (from a few months ago) and I have a CSV file:

```
search,min_results
test,1000
testing,50
...
```

I would, ideally, like to check that the number of results are equal or greater than the min_results column, something like:

```
.get(...)
.check(
    jsonPath("$..results")
    .count
    .is(>= "${min_results}".toInt)
```

The last line doesn't work as it probably isn't valid Scala but also`"${min_results}".toInt` tries to convert `${min_results}` rather than its value to an `Int`.

I would settle for just fixing the conversion `toInt` problem but this might result in a slightly less robust script. However, I could then add a `max_results` column and use the `.in(xx to yy)`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, *toInt* definitely won't work, as it would be called before the EL has been resolved.

However, this code snippet would achieve what you want :

```
.get(...)
.check(
    jsonPath("$...results")
    .count
    .greaterThanOrEqual(session => session("min_results").as[String].toInt))
```

Here, using *as[Int]* works as expected, since the min_results attribute has already been resolved from the session at this point.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, however this seems to error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer". What might be the reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, my bad. min_results is indeed stored as a String. You'll have to resort to a _toInt_ call to convert the String to a Integer. I'll modify my answer to a fully working solution.